# Invalidating JWTs on sign out?

Tags: security, authentication, jwt

I'm new to JWT and was wondering if it is possible to invalidate/void JWTs on the server-side when a user signs out of an application (I'm also wondering if it even *makes sense* to do so!). Idea is:

1. User clicks a sign out link in their app
2. App makes a call to `POST https://api.myapp.example.com/auth/invalidate`
3. The JWT (which is an authorization/bearer token in the HTTP request header) is somehow invalidated
4. Now, no one can ever use that JWT again

I'm not sure if this is an unorthodox approach to signout logic or not, or whether its acceptable to just let the JWT linger as valid, even after the user signs out (I guess I could shorten the life of the JWT expiry to, say, 60 mins or something).

So again: wondering if its possible to do this kind of "*invalidation*" using (and if so, **how?!**) as well as whether it even makes sense to do this (and if not, what does a typical signout flow look like?!). Thanks!

Comment: You just put the finger on one of the flaws of using a JWT for login authentification (IMO). The token includes the expiration inside itself, you can't actually modify its expiration without creation a brand new token. You could add a secondary system for the server to be able to reject tokens on specific conditions, but that's falling back to a traditional login system, you loose the portability of the access token. You can simply delete the token from the client side, but you can't be sure the user didn't keep it and try to use it again after logout..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the token expiration date (stated in the [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) claim) I can think of a couple of ways of *invalidating* a JWT token:

#### Changing the key

The first approach requires changing the key used to sign the token on server side, but it doesn't seem to be practical for the situation described in your question.

#### Whitelisting the token identifiers

Another approach (and probably the one that suits you better) involves keeping the track of the token in a whitelist on server side.

- When issuing a token, use the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim to store a unique identifier in the token. Also add this unique identifier to the whitelist on server side.
- When validating the token (besides checking the signature, the expiration date and other claims you may need to), ensure that the value of the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim is whitelisted.
- When a user requests to invalidate the token, remove the token identifier from the whitelist.

For the token identifier, you can use [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122)s.

JWT allows you to perform *stateless authentication* (once you validate the signature, you can trust the token and then perform authentication without depending on external entities). The whitelist approach is a trade off, in case you need to track the tokens you have issued.

Comment: Thanks @Cassio (+1) I think I like your whitelist/token ID approach. Two quick followup questions if you don't mind me asking: **(1)** Above, you state "*That's not really stateless though*" as if going with this solution is either creating a problem or violating some principle. Would you mind elaborating on this a little bit? Meaning: why is it "bad" for JWTs to be "stateful"? And **(2)** I assume that for the whitelist I could use anything I wanted: MySQL DB table, etc. Yes? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb **(1)** My statement should be _"That's not really stateless **authentication** though"_. One of the great advantages of JWT is that it's a self contained token and allows you to perform _stateless authentication_. That is, once you validate the signature, you can trust the token and perform authentication without depending on external entities. However, if you need to invalidate a particular token, you should keep the track of it (using the whitelist approach, for example).

Comment: @smeeb **(2)** For the whitelist you can use what suits you best: SQL or NoSQL databases. You may also want to store the expiration date along with the token identifier, so you can remove the identifiers for the tokens that have expired.